# Not able to enter value in Textbox using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, html, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using `Selenium` `WebDriver` to enter text in 2 `textboxe` using java. I am able to enter text in the 1st text box but for the  2nd `textbox` I keep getting `ElementNotVisibleException`

**HTML code**..

```
<form name="form">
  <div class="form-group">
      <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="name" placeholder="Name*" required>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email" ng-change="(form.email.$dirty && form.email.$valid) ? error='' : error='Please enter a valid email'" placeholder="Email*" required autofocus/>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Java Code**..

```
WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.name("name"));  
name.sendKeys("Sample Name");

WebElement signup_email = driver.findElement(By.name("email")); 
signup_email.sendKeys("abc@xyz.com");
```

**Error**:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not
>   currently  visible and so may not be interacted with   Command
>   duration or timeout: 19 milliseconds   Build info: version: '2.53.1',
>   revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'   System info: host:
>   'Hp-PC', ip: '172.16.255.131', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64',
>   os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'   Session ID:
>   2e7ab2fd-cd6b-428e-86e7-a4f7d8d737fa   Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver   Capabilities
>   [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true,   javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=47.0.1}]
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:122)
>   at src.tests.EmailSignUp.test(EmailSignUp.java:107) at
>   src.tests.EmailSignUp.main(EmailSignUp.java:27)

**Edit 1**:

In the Browser Console the following classes are being automatically being populated by angular Js

[image: Email_Console]

I can't understand where I'm going wrong in case of 2nd `textbox`. Is the angular code causing problems?? Please Help..

Comment: As far as i can see, there is nothing wrong in your code. I guess its problem with the page it-self. As a work around you can try Explicit wait with expected condition of visibility.

Comment: tried that..I'm getting a TimedOutException... :(

Comment: Are you able to enter values manually? May be you  can try increasing  time span

Comment: Pause the execution till entering the first text box value and then see the state of the element2 before trying to find it. May be it can give you some info

Comment: Have you checked if the selector for the element that is not visible matches multiple elements in the page? You can use a css like: [name=email]

Comment: @lauda You are right! @Lucy Are you sure there is only one email field in your DOM with `name=email` ? Because, I had faced similar issue where in I had multiple buttons with same id.

Comment: Is it public web app? can you share link to the resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be when you are going to locate element, it would not be present on the `DOM`, You should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element present as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

WebElement name = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("name")));
name.sendKeys("Sample Name");

WebElement signup_email = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("email")));
signup_email.sendKeys("abc@xyz.com");
```

**Edited1** :- If you are still facing the issue during `sendKeys()`, I think some javascript embedded in your element which makes it invisible, in this case try to set value using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
WebElement signup_email = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("email")));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value = 'abc@xyz.com'", signup_email);
```

**Edited1**:- If you want to make element visible, if not sure what exactly css work in your element but below is the generic way to make is visible as below :-

```
WebElement signup_email = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("email")));
signup_email = (WebElement)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; return arguments[0];", signup_email);

//Now if it is visible then goto set value
signup_email.sendKeys("abc@xyz.com");
```

**Edited** :- As I see this element is works with `angularjs`, try `angularjs` stuff to set value on this using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :

```
WebElement signup_email = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("email")));

((JavascriptExecutor).executeScript("angular.element(arguments[0]).scope().email = arguments[1]", signup_email, "abc@xyz.com");
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: I'm getting an exception org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.name: email

Comment: @Lucy try then using `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated`..see updated answer..

Comment: Now getting "ElementNotVisibleException"

Comment: @Lucy Ok then try using `JavascriptExecutor` to set value, see edited answer..hope it works..:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur, But when we are not able to locate the element. will javascript execute?

Comment: @Siva No, you are able to locate, problem is when you are using `sendKeys()`, see exception carefully, it states can not be intracted with the element means when selenium goes to set value, I think some java script would be embedded that's why it can not be interacted with the element..:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur. When using JavascriptExecutor I'm not getting an exception in eclipse console but the value is still not getting poplulated.. When using the method "isDisplayed()" the value being returned is false i.e element is not visible...is there any way to make it visible?

Comment: @SaurabhGaur. Sorry i misunderstood the exception

Comment: @Lucy yes, you can make it visible using `JavascriptExecutor `, could you tell me what exactly css embedded which makes it invisible??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I can't find any embedded css which is making it hidden..is there a way to make it visible by force in selenium? As you can see in the screen shot in question the input element is not hidden..

Comment: @Lucy I'm not sure without seeing your Live Html, but  provided you generic way to make element visible, try edited answer and let me know..:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Even after adding the inline css property style="visibility:visible;" and using your code in edited answer I'm still getting ElementNotVisibleException

Comment: @Lucy try second edited answer.. you can set value using angularjs stuff.. try it and let me know...:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I tried your second edited answer. I'm not getting any exceptions but still the the email field is not visible hence not getting poplulated..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Now it's working..actually i was loading another html page dynamically having the same name. When I changed the name to "email_1" the code worked properly..