# Selenium can't find element which is visible

Tags: java, selenium

This is HTML where I try to find selected input

[image: HTML]

I try to sendkey() to this input like this

```
String xPath = "//*[@id='id_username']";

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xPath))).sendKeys("text");
```

Always get this error `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException`. Usually I get this error when element is not visible in setted time.

There is no iframe in entire html.

Which may be the cause?

Comment: Did you try with sleep of 1 or 2 second?

Comment: @VinitMehta I have a sleep of 5 seconds before this.

Comment: Check whether form located inside a frame/iframe

Comment: May be when you are going to locate element, it would not be present on the DOM.

Comment: Or you can try with JavascriptExecutor.

Comment: @Andersson he mentioned already that there is not iframe in entire html page.

Comment: @Andersson There is no frame/iframe.

Comment: @raul1ro , try `presenceOfElementLocated` instead of `visibilityOfElementLocated`. @Vinit Mehta , thanks, missed that

Comment: @VinitMehta I am almost 100% this is present on DOM. From my knowledge you can't send text via javascript. How that can be done?

Comment: You used `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` which detect element visibility until element visible or timeout, You need to change to another expect condition, like `presenceOfElementLocated`

Comment: If I use `presence...` I get `ElementNotVisibleException` . This is weird.

Comment: @raul1ro Please see answer :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38789445/not-able-to-enter-value-in-textbox-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: There are two possible reasons. 1) Duplicate xpath. 2) May be extra popup is open while entering text into input box.

Comment: When you write Xpath in developer console , then how many entries are present ? Have you tried to include both presenceofelement and visibilityofelement

Comment: The real problem was Duplicate xPath. how @VinitMehta said. There is a `div` with `display:none`, above my `form`, which contain another input with same id. Thank you guys.

Comment: Great! you found solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider a couple of points as follows:

- Instead of `String` try to define the *xpath* as an object of `By`.
- Moving forward as you are invoking `sendKeys()` instead of *ExpectedConditions* method *visibilityOfElementLocated()* use *elementToBeClickable()* method.
- As the element is an `<input>` try to construct a granular *xpath*
- Your code block will be as:

  ```
  By xPath = By.xpath("//form[@action='/accounts/register/']/fieldset[@class='fieldset_main']//input[@id='id_username' and @name='username']");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(xPath)).sendKeys("text");
  ```

Comment: How element can be clickable if it is not visible? By the way, real problem was duplicate xpath. There was another `input` with same `id `but in a `div` with `display:none`, and all of this was above my `input`.

Comment: Give it a try and let me know the status

Comment: Your code work, because you settled in which segment of code to looking for input, and there is no duplicate input.

Comment: Of-coarse that should be the ideal approach through getting granular